# How to make a button do the same thing on every screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a "Log Out" button in the toolbar (made through the storyboard) of every screen of my app. I would like it to perform the same action no matter which page is showing when it is tapped.

Is there a way to have all these buttons do the same thing without having to create the same `IBAction` method in every view controller (I have a bunch of different types of view controllers)?

Comment: You could have a common superclass for all your view controllers and add the button in that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to share the button across all toolbars. This is both ugly and difficult. My preference is to encapsulate the logout logic in its own class and then call it from all the buttons:

```
#import "AccountManager.h"

@implementation AccountManager

+ (id)sharedManager
{
    static AccountManager *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[AccountManager alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedManager;
}

- (void)logout
{
    // logout logic
}

@end
```

Then in your view controller you can have

```
#import "AccountManager.h"

- (IBAction)didSelectLogout:(id)sender
{
    [[AccountManager sharedManager] logout];
}
```

In this case, you still have an action in each controller, but your logout logic is not spread throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I needed a button on many viewControllers. Tapping on it will go to the itunes link of paid version. This is what I did.

CustomButton.h

```
+(void)createDownloadFullVersionButton:(UIButton*)button
```

CustomButton.m

```
+(void)createDownloadFullVersionButton:(UIButton*)button
{
//    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
// Since the buttons can be any width we use a thin image with a stretchable center point
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_slice.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0];
UIImage *buttonPressedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_slice_over.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0];
[button.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
[button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

[button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor]];
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(actionDownloadPaidVersion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//CGRect buttonFrame = [button frame];
//buttonFrame.size.width = 220;
//buttonFrame.size.height = 48;
//[button setFrame:buttonFrame];

[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonPressedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fullversion_icon.png"];
UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((button.frame.size.height - (image.size.width / 2))/2, (button.frame.size.height - (image.size.width / 2))/2, image.size.width / 2, image.size.height / 2)];
iconView.image = image;
[button addSubview:iconView];
[iconView release];

UILabel     *iconLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(iconView.frame.origin.x * 2 + iconView.frame.size.width, (button.frame.size.height - (image.size.width / 2))/2, 180, 24)];
iconLabel.text = @"Download Full Version";
iconLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
iconLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
iconLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
iconLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
iconLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
[button addSubview:iconLabel];
[iconLabel release];

}

+(void)actionDownloadPaidVersion:(id)sender
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/app/filehider/id475295711"]];
}
```

Now on the viewControllers where I need to have the button.

1. Add a simple button (buttonAd).
2. Call createDownloadFullVersionButton method of CustomButton with parameter buttonAd like this:

   ```
   [CustomBarButton createDownloadFullVersionButton:buttonAd];
   ```